# What does this error about in Wordpress React? Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8090

Tags: wordpress, reactjs

When i start a react using npm run wpstart for Wordpress Theme is starts for the first time perfectly, but for the second time when i start it again to run a theme it throws all the time this kind of error. I have given a full permission to my project folder.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v8.15.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle wpproject@0.1.0~prestart: wpproject@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle wpproject@0.1.0~start: wpproject@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle wpproject@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle wpproject@0.1.0~start: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/var/www/html/projectname/wp-content/themes/wpproject/react-src/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
9 verbose lifecycle wpproject@0.1.0~start: CWD: /var/www/html/projectname/wp-content/themes/wpproject/react-src
10 silly lifecycle wpproject@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'wptheme-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle wpproject@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle wpproject@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: wpproject@0.1.0 start: `wptheme-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid wpproject@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /var/www/html/projectname/wp-content/themes/wpproject/react-src
16 verbose Linux 4.15.0-45-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "start"
18 verbose node v8.15.0
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error wpproject@0.1.0 start: `wptheme-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the wpproject@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: @graycharry I have answered your question, please have a look and mark as accepted if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error EADDRINUSE :::8090 means the port in which you are trying to run the project is in use, to avoid this error you can kill the process running on the port and run the project.